# Calling JavaScript object method from QML ListView delegate

Tags: javascript, qt, qml

I have a ListView with a list of JavaScript objects as a model. The delegate needs to respond to click and I want to store click handler attached to model item (`action` property):

```
ListView {
    id: idListView
    model: [
        {
            name: "Item 1",
            icon: "icon1.svg",
            action: function() {
                //do stuff
            }
        },
        /* other items */
    ]
    delegate: MyDelegate {
        name: modelData.name
        icon: modelData.icon

        MouseArea {
            anchors.fill: parent
            onClicked {
                modelData.action()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But when I click on an item i get

> TypeError: Property 'action' of object [object Object] is not a function

What's the proper way to attach function to object and call it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should define function as a QML property. `Object` doesn't allow that so you could use `ListModel` instead:

```
import QtQuick 2.11
import QtQuick.Window 2.11

Window {
    id: root
    visible: true
    width:480
    height: 640
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    ListView {
        anchors.fill: parent
        spacing: 2
        model: ListModel {
            ListElement {
                name: "Item 1"
                property var func: function(){ console.log("Item 1 clicked"); }
            }
            ListElement {
                name: "Item 2"
                property var func: function(){ console.log("Item 2 clicked"); }
            }
        }

        delegate: Rectangle {
            height: 30
            color: "#EFEFEF"
            border { width: 1; color: "#CCC" }
            width: parent.width
            Text {
                text: name
                anchors.centerIn: parent
            }
            MouseArea {
                anchors.fill: parent
                onClicked: {
                    if(typeof func === "function")
                        func();
                    else
                        console.error("Click handler not defined");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Another but a bit tricked solution:

```
import QtQuick 2.11
import QtQuick.Window 2.11

Window {
    id: root
    visible: true
    width:480
    height: 640
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    ListView {
        anchors.fill: parent
        spacing: 2
        property list<QtObject> arr: [
            QtObject {
                property string name: "Item 1"
                property var func: function(){ console.log("Item 1 clicked"); }
            },
            QtObject {
                property string name: "Item 2"
                property var func: function(){ console.log("Item 2 clicked"); }
            }
        ]
        model: arr

        delegate: Rectangle {
            height: 30
            color: "#EFEFEF"
            border { width: 1; color: "#CCC" }
            width: parent.width
            Text {
                text: modelData.name ? modelData.name : "Undefined item"
                anchors.centerIn: parent
            }
            MouseArea {
                anchors.fill: parent
                onClicked: {
                    if(typeof modelData.func === "function")
                        modelData.func();
                    else
                        console.error("Click handler not defined");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you test the first snippet? I don't think functions can be used in `ListElement`.

Comment: Yes, tested in 5.11. Fist I've posted the second example, with `QtObject`s then I decided to try the same thing with `ListElement` and was surprised to see that it works. A `ListElement` can have only simple types but nothing said about `property` :-)

Comment: Direct use of ListElement doesn't worked for me, because it doesn't handle QmlEngine dynamic retranslate. Second options looks nice (and works), despite being more verbose - I was seeking a way to attach handler to model item.

Comment: It is indeed new in Qt 5.11: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-models-listelement.html - "Beginning with Qt 5.11 ListElement also allows assigning a function declaration to a role. This allows the definition of ListElements with callable actions."

Comment: First variant still return error in 5.12: `ListElement: cannot use script for property value`. What correct syntax should be here? No sample in the doc.

Comment: 2nd variant works! Thanks much! Created bug report: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-80041

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately it is not possible to store a function inside a [`ListElement`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-models-listelement.html):

> Values must be simple constants; either strings (quoted and optionally
>   within a call to QT_TR_NOOP), boolean values (true, false), numbers,
>   or enumeration values (such as AlignText.AlignHCenter).

A simple way to call a function from a delegate is to keep the function outside of the model and reference its name in the model:

```
ListView {
    id: idListView

    readonly property var actions: {
        "action1": function() {
            console.log("called action 1!");
        },
        "action2": function() {
            console.log("called action 2!");
        }
    }

    model: [
        {
            name: "Item 1",
            icon: "icon1.svg",
            action: "action1"
        },
        {
            name: "Item 2",
            icon: "icon2.svg",
            action: "action2"
        },
        /* other items */
    ]
    delegate: MyDelegate {
        name: modelData.name
        icon: modelData.icon

        MouseArea {
            anchors.fill: parent
            onClicked: {
                if (typeof idListView.actions[modelData.action] === "function") {
                    idListView.actions[modelData.action]()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion! So, model items are converted to ListElements despite regardless of model type?

Comment: No, I don't think so. I think augre was referring to folibis' answer.

Comment: I am not sure. I used the doc of `ListElement` because I believe it is the same behavior as using an object for the model (with same possible values). But I am not really aware of how exactly the model is managed using an object VS `ListModel`. Anyway I didn’t think of using properties, if you don’t mind using a `ListModel` I find fobilis’ answer a good alternative since you don’t have to rely on the function names!

Comment: Thanks much! Above is the only workaround for [QTBUG-80041](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-80041).

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar issue. I wanted to have a `Drawer` containing a `ListView` of `Action`s. Some try and error and finally got it running (Qt 5.11). May my code is of use for someone else.

```
Action {
    id: aboutAction
    text: "About"
    icon.source: "icon_info.png"
}

Drawer {
    edge: Qt.LeftEdge
    width: Screen.pixelDensity * 100  // mm
    height: parent.height

    ListView {
        id: listView
        anchors.fill: parent

        model: ListModel {}

        delegate: ItemDelegate {
            width: parent.width
            action: action_
        }
    }

    Component.onCompleted: {
        listView.model.append({action_: aboutAction});
    }
}
```